# View with url aliases

Tags: uri, path-aliases

I am writing a view that lists all content of a specific type. I would like to, additionally, be able to set paths to content made by a specific user. For example drupal.dd/content will give all content. Then drupal.dd/%/content will show only the content by a specific user where % is the user's name. The issue I have come across is, when I create the path with /%/content it says the first segment of the path cannot be %. I am using a contextual filter to filter by author. How would I go about doing so. I am using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have a path for this at drupal.dd/content/[author] based on how you have setup the contextual filter. If you are using a contextual filter, they will get appended to the path of the view, and it sounds like your view has a path of "/content".

Comment: Is there a way to do /%/content ? Without withing the contextual filter perhaps?

Comment: I assume you are asking about still utilizing views. As you mentioned, you cannot have a wildcard as the first part of the path. So you could put something else there to have it be /[something]/%/content. Is there a reason that you are opposed to just using "/content" as everything and "/content/[author]" as the filter by author?

Comment: I am recreating an existing site in Drupal 8 that is currently using Drupal 6. The current format must be maintained :/. Is there a way to do this which would not be using views?

Comment: How was it done on the 6 site? did they do a custom module with a hook_menu and define a page callback for the "%/content" paths? You can do a similar thing in 8 using routes with wildcards as well.

Comment: Just follow the conventions. A route should not start with a contextual filter.

Comment: Could you possibly link me to some good conventions regarding this use case? I am a brand new Drupal developer (actually fairly new to web dev in general), only been doing this for about a month. I don't know how it was done on the 6 site but I can look into it.